# When was Timothy in prison?

Tags: hebrews, chronology

Hebrews 13:23

> Know ye that our brother Timothy is set at liberty; with whom, if he
> come shortly, I will see you.

When was Timothy in prison?

---

Note-this question assumes an affirmative answer to [this](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33566/does-%CE%B1%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%BB%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BD-refer-to-release-from-prison-in-hebrews-1323) previous question. That Timothy was in prison has been the general but not universal interpretation of verse 23.

Comment: Up-voted +1, but I am personally more interested in why the verse is there, in an unattributed epistle, than the exact detail of where and when Timothy required 'release'.

Answer (score 2):

**When was Timothy in prison?**

It appears that Timothy personally endured imprisonment at Rome sometime within the period between the writing of the letter to the Philippians and the one to the Hebrews.​

Philippians 2:19 NASB

> 19 But I hope, in the Lord Jesus, to send Timothy to you shortly, so
> that I also may be encouraged when I learn of your condition.

Hebrews 13:23

> Know ye that our brother Timothy is set at liberty;{from prison} with
> whom, if he come shortly, I will see you.

Brittanica -Letter of Paul to the Philippians

https://www.britannica.com/topic/Letter-of-Paul-to-the-Philippians

Letter of Paul to the Philippians, also called Epistle of St. Paul the Apostle to the Philippians, abbreviation Philippians, eleventh book of the New Testament, written by St. Paul the Apostle to the Christian congregation he had established in Philippi. It was penned while he was in prison, probably at Rome or Ephesus, **about 62 CE.** In its present canonical form, Philippians is, according to several scholars, a later collection of fragments of the correspondence(s) of Paul with the congregation in Philippi.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_to_the_Hebrews

The use of tabernacle terminology in Hebrews has been used to date the epistle before the destruction of the temple, the idea being that knowing about the destruction of both Jerusalem and the temple would have influenced the development of the author's overall argument. Therefore, the most probable date for its composition is the second half of the year 63 or the beginning of 64, according to the Catholic Encyclopedia.[21]

According to Brittanica Paul's Epistle to the Philippians was written about 62 C.E. and at this time as mentioned in Philippians 2:19, Paul hopes to send Timothy to them. Hence Timothy was not in prison this time.

In Hebrews 13:23  Paul's mentioned that Timothy was released from prison. According to Wikipedia the Epistle to the Hebrews was written in the second half of 63 or the beginning of 64.

**This indicates that Timothy was most likely in prison ln the second half of 62 to the first half of 63 C.E.**